# Java - Variable definition of an object

Tags: java, object, javafx, tableview

My issue is the following : I read a `.csv` file and convert it into an `ArrayList`. In order to put this `ArrayList` in a javafx `TableView`, I need to create an object, go through `ObservableList<Object> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList()` and populate it with as much as `new Object()` as I need. The point is that in my `.csv`, the number of columns may differ in each run of my program, so the object definition does. I don't know how to define an object which definition is a function of the length of my `ArrayList` and the attributes aren't always the same (and I can't find any clue on google).

To illustrate, imagine the following code :

```
public class SettingData extends Application {
   public void start(Stage stage) {
      TableView<FileData> table = new TableView<FileData>();
      final ObservableList<FileData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
         new FileData("file1", "D:\\myFiles\\file1.txt", "25 MB", "12/01/2017"),
         new FileData("file2", "D:\\myFiles\\file2.txt", "30 MB", "01/11/2019"),
         new FileData("file3", "D:\\myFiles\\file3.txt", "50 MB", "12/04/2017"),
         new FileData("file4", "D:\\myFiles\\file4.txt", "75 MB", "25/09/2018")
      );

      TableColumn fileNameCol = new TableColumn("File Name");
      fileNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fileName"));
      TableColumn pathCol = new TableColumn("Path");
      pathCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("path"));
      TableColumn sizeCol = new TableColumn("Size");
      sizeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("size"));
      TableColumn dateCol = new TableColumn("Date Modified");
      dateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("dateModified"));
      
      ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      table.setItems(data);
      table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
      table.getColumns().addAll(fileNameCol, pathCol, sizeCol, dateCol);
```

Assuming that we define `FileData` like this :

```
public class FileData {
   SimpleStringProperty fileName;
   SimpleStringProperty path;
   SimpleStringProperty size;
   SimpleStringProperty dateModified;
   FileData(String fileName, String path, String size, String dateModified) {
      this.fileName = new SimpleStringProperty(fileName);
      this.path = new SimpleStringProperty(path);
      this.size = new SimpleStringProperty(size);
      this.dateModified = new SimpleStringProperty(dateModified);
   }
   public String getFileName(){
      return fileName.get();
   }
   public void setFileName(String fname){
      fileName.set(fname);
   }
   public String getPath(){
      return path.get();
   }
   public void setPath(String fpath){
      path.set(fpath);
   }
   public String getSize(){
      return size.get();
   }
   public void setSize(String fsize){
      size.set(fsize);
   }
   public String getDateModified(){
      return dateModified.get();
   }
   public void setModified(String fmodified){
      dateModified.set(fmodified);
   }
}
```

How may implement my code to handle the fact that once I may not have `size` columns, or another time I'll have a `author` column. (In fact, the file I'm working with carries around 80 to 110 columns, that's why I need to have a "modular" definition of my object).

It's my first post on any forum ever, I'm not familiar with your usages, sorry for that.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: are you talking about lamdas

Comment: if so use: Supplier<Integer> lengthSupplier = () -> myList.size();

Comment: but I really don't understand what you want. Maybe you could provide some code

Comment: You may check what I added :)

Comment: Just represent each row with a `List<String>`, so you have a `TableView<List<String>>`. Read the file into an `ObservableList<List<String>>` which you set as the table's items. As you parse the file, keep track of the longest row, and then create that many columns as `TableColumn<List<String>, String>`.

Comment: @James_D do you mean that I don't need a class to fill a TableView ? I looked for that earlier but I didn't find any cases.

Comment: Well, `List` is a class, so in a sense, yes, you still "need a class to fill a `TableView`". You're just using a library class instead of your own class.